# Safari 7.0.3 animate ScrollTop div not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm having trouble getting a #div with overflow:scroll to animate and scroll down to a specific part within the div in Safari 7.0.3.

It works just fine in FF, Opera, Chrome, but I can't get it to work in Safari for some reason? Does anybody know why and how I can work around this? 
I've tried setting the #menuContainer to relative positioning, and it works but badly. It will work sometimes and other times it won't.

**CSS**

```
#menu{
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
}

#menuContainer{
   position:absolute;
   overflow: scroll;
   width: 350px;
   right: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="menuContainer">
        <ul>
           <li></li>
           <li></li>
           <li>.....
        <ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#menuContainer").animate({scrollTop: $("li:nth-child("+varJumpTo+")").offset().top}, 500);
```

Comment: You really just need to debug things first. What values are you getting from `.offset().top`? Are all your elements being found? Does `varJumpTo` contain the value you expect? Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, and the value within varJumpTo is correct. I shortened the code in order to simplify the problem. The value of .offset().top was incorrect (technically correct, since it calculated the position before all the content within the #menuContainer was being loaded but incorrect for the results I needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

It seems like in Safari it's best to .animate() scollTop after all of the content is loaded. So adding this around jQuery works:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   $("#menuContainer").animate({scrollTop: $("li:nth-child("+varJumpTo+")").offset().top}, 500);
});
```

It was acting wonky because all of the content within the list needed to be loaded before we calculated the top() position of the div offset().

Thanks! I hope this helps someone else out :D